# How to remove the root of an binary tree in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

How to remove the root of a binary tree?

```
private static  NodeClass remove(int deleteThisItem, NodeClass item) { 
        deleted=false;
        if(item==null)                    
            return item;  

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    if(deleteThisItem<item.value)
        item.left=remove(deleteThisItem,item.left);

    else if(deleteThisItem>item.value)
        item.right=remove(deleteThisItem,item.right);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
deleted=false;
    if(item==null)                  
        return item;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    if(deleteThisItem<item.value)
        item.left=remove(deleteThisItem,item.left);

    else if(deleteThisItem>item.value)
        item.right=remove(deleteThisItem,item.right);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    else if(deleteThisItem==item.value){
            if(item.left!=null&&item.right!=null){
            item.value=findMax(item.left).value;        
            item.left=remove(item.value,item.left); 
            deleted=true;
        }
        else if(item.left!=null){
            item=item.left;
            deleted=true;
        }
        else if( item.right!=null){
            item=item.right;
            deleted=true;
        }

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("hata");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return item;
```

This is my remove method. This method working very well, but I cannot remove the root.
This is in my main method:

```
if(command.equals("R")){
            int value=scan.nextInt();
            remove(value) ;
            if(getDeleted())
            System.out.println(value+" removed.");
            else
                System.out.println(value+" cannot found in the tree!.");
        }
```

For example if tree's root is 10, and I want to remove it.When I tried to remove it, I got :

> 10 cannot found in the tree!.

Im calling remove like :

```
private static boolean deleted=false;

public static void remove(int key) { //This method called from my main
    root=remove(key,root);  
}   

public static boolean getDeleted(){
    return deleted;
}
```

Comment: Is this your own Binary Tree? Or the one built into Java? What is the top code block? (I can't find a better way to ask that last question). Please give use some more information so we can better help you.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer AFAIK there's no built-in binary tree data structure in Java. `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` (that uses `TreeMap` behind the scenes) use a red black tree for their implementation, but after that, there's no tree structure in the JDK.

Comment: Ok. I have two classes, one of them is my main class and the other one is my Tree class. Im adding some numbers to my binary tree and then Im deleting some numbers from it. I can add numbers very well and I can delete them as well, but I cannot delete the root of the binary.

Comment: 2 __7_5       
 I can delete 7 and 5 but I cannot delete 2 from my tree.

Comment: `deleted=false;`  -- is this defined inside your **`remove(value) ; `** method? or where is `deleted`   variable defined? -- also can you include complete method remove here.. like `public void remove(....)`?

Comment: Please post your tree class then. And thanks @LuiggiMendoza, for some reason I forgot that. I haven't done too much Java in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete your root node because your code is missing an `else` statement after your inner `if / else if / else if` statements. That means that you are not covering all cases (tree with a single node is one such case).

Right after

```
else if(item.right != null)
{
    item = item.right;
    deleted = true;
}
```

add an `else` block

```
else
{
    item = null;
    deleted = true;
}
```

Comment: Ohh. I  thought I wrote it  at the beginning of the System.out.println("hata");. Thank you so much it worked! :)